# Json no se renderiza dentro de una tabla HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

El json por consola me muestra los datos pero al llamarlos dentro de una tabla html no me deja ver.

Código html

```
    <button id="agregar1"> agregar </button>
    <table border="1px solid black">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>nombre_pro</th>
    <th>descripcion</th>
    <th>codigo</th>
    <th>imagen</th>
    <th>precio</th>
    <th>action</th>
    </tr>       
    </thead>    
    <tbody id="tabla" >     
    </tbody >
  </table>
```

Código js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#agregar1").click(function(){
   var lj= $.get('http://localhost/cordoba2db/www/php/lista.php', function(data){

console.log(data);
     $("#tabla").html("");
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

        var tr =$('<tr>')

            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].id_pro+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].nombre_pro+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].descri_pro+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].codigo_pro+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].imagen_pro+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].precio_pro+"</td>");


        $("#tabla").append(tr)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Código json con php

```
<?php


$servidor ="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$clave="";
$base="prueba";
 $objetoMysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave,$base);


 if ($objetoMysqli ->connect_errno){
    die("Error de conexión: " . $objetoMysqli->mysqli_connect_errno() . ", " . $objetoMysqli->mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
else{
    echo "La conexión tuvo éxito";
}


$sql="select * from productos ";
mysqli_set_charset($objetoMysqli, "utf8"); 

//mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($objetoMysqli, $sql)) die();

$productos = array(); //creamos un array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id_pro=$row['id_pro'];
    $nombre_pro=$row['nombre_pro'];
    $descri_pro=$row['descri_pro'];
    $imagen_pro=$row['imagen_pro'];
    $precio_pro=$row['precio_pro'];


    $productos[] = array('id_pro'=> $id_pro, 'nombre_pro'=> $nombre_pro,'descri_pro'=> $descri_pro, 'imagen_pro'=> $imagen_pro,
                        'precio_pro'=> $precio_pro);

}

//desconectamos la base de datos
$close = mysqli_close($objetoMysqli) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");


//Creamos el JSON
$json_string = json_encode($productos);
echo $json_string;
```

Comment: al pasarlos en json me deja ver todos los datos que hay denntro del mysql pero al pasarlos en la tabla html no me deja ver nada por favor si laguien me  puede ayudar con este problemilla se lo agradezco

Comment: Hola, al parecer tu código esta mas pegado en el ciclo for, sin eso no podemos ver que está pasando. Una duda, ¿estás convirtiendo `data` en un objeto? Esto lo puedes hacer de esta forma: `var dataObjecto = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: El `tr` no cierra visualializa en el inspector que te esta agregando al doom fuera de que creo los json no tienen una propiedad `lenght` intenta con `for(let x in data)`

Comment: for(let x in data) lo hice con este. pero aun no me muestra los datos que esta en json. me aparece en el la tabla html  en las casillas undefined

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en que los json no tienen una propiedad `length` pero puedes hacer esto:

```
let str="";
for(let i in data){

  str+=`<tr>
  <td> ${data[i].id_pro} </td>
  <td> ${data[i].nombre_pro} </td>
  <td> ${data[i].descri_pro} </td>
  <td> ${data[i].codigo_pro} </td>
  <td> ${data[i].imagen_pro} </td>
  <td> ${data[i].precio_pro} </td>
  </tr>
  `;

}
console.log(str);
$("#tabla").append(str);
```

Comment: hice lo que tu me dijistes pero aun me sigue apareciendo lo mismo

Comment: Podrias publicar la estructura o un ejemplo de tu json editando tu pregunta